# If a integer value is changed to a float, how do you change if it is an integer to float?

Tags: python

Basically using the input(). Here is the example code:

```
a1 = input("Number1? ")
a2 = input("Number2? ")
if a1.is_float():
 a1 = float(a1)
if a2.is_float():
 a2 = float(a2)
```

When I type first number (0.5)
Then second number (0.5)
It shows that it is a float. However, the code before that I wrote for a1 and a2 to be an integer. I want it to give the answer if the numbers are floats, or integers. Without having to use any other functions. (I used functions in my code). Just one function. Any solutions?

Comment: Most math operations in Python work equally well on ints and floats.  Do you really need to care?

Comment: I also used the code `if a1.is_integer():` and for a2, however it still won't work.

Comment: Oh. and I forgot to mention I converted it from string to float / int.

Comment: You haven't showed us what you DO with the variables, so we can't give you any advice.

Comment: There is no `str.is_float()` method. How is this code working at all?

Comment: If you just call `float(a1)` on a numeric string it will produce a float even if the input didn't contain a decimal point.  The only question here is what you want to do if the input is something like `"asdf"`.  Is raising a `ValueError` okay in that situation?

Comment: I use the int("1") because that is actually an integer in a string. I mean about checking if it is a real float (0.1) so it adds the floats. Otherwise, If it is not an integer or float (In any value except str(), then it will check. Basically I mean I need it to check if it is a real integer (1) or real float(1.5) for both numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number 12 (for example) is a valid integer and is a valid float, since floats don't need to have a decimal point. If you really want to distinguish them, you need to check for integer first, then float:

```
from validate import is_float, is_integer
a1 = input("Number1? ")
if is_integer(a1):
    a1 = int(a1)
elif is_float(a1):
    a1 = float(a1)
else:
    pass # neither float nor integer
```

Likewise for `a2`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's code that asks for and validates an integer, and a float, and uses them in a computation.  Perhaps this will lead to happiness.

```
def getInteger(prompt):
    while True:
        val = input(prompt)
        if val.isdigit():
            return int(val)
        print("That's not an integer")

def getFloat(prompt):
    while True:
        val = input(prompt)
        try:
            return float(val)
        except ValueError:
            print("That's not a float")

a1 = getInteger( "give me an int: " )
a2 = getFloat( "give me a float: " )

print( a1 ** a2 )
```

Thomas's response leads me to think I may have misinterpreted the rather poorly-worded problem statement.  Here is my code, modified to return an integer if it is an integer, otherwise a float.

```
def getValue(prompt):
    while True:
        val = input(prompt)
        if val.isdigit():
            return int(val)
        try:
            return float(val)
        except ValueError:
            print("That's neither an integer or a float")

a1 = getValue( "give me an int: " )
a2 = getValue( "give me a float: " )

print( a1 ** a2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

input function returns a string, not a number.
'str' object doesn't have any method or attribute called 'is_float'.

However, for integer there is a method called isdigit(). returns True only if the string is in integer format.

example:

```
s="34"
print(s.isdigit()) // True
```

So for integer, you can make a simple code like this.

```
a1=input("Number? ")
if a1.isdigit():
    a1=int(a1)
else:
    print("wrong format")
```

now for float, there isn't any method like that.
so you can either 1) use try-except block or 2) use regex to do that

1. try-except

example:

```
a1=input("Number? ")
try:
    a1=float(a1)
except ValueError as e:
    print("wrong format")
```

2. regex

example:

```
import re
pattern = r'^\s*[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\s*$'
a1=input("Number? ")
if re.fullmatch(pattern, a1):
    a1=float(a1)
else:
    print("wrong format")
```